# How do I fix the pip error in python when the requirement is not found?

Tags: python, pip

downloaded the latest python 3.11.1 and trying to install the modules I had on the 3.9 version. getting an error that says "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement..."

what is it that I am doing wrong, please?

```
C:\>pip install win32com
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
wind32com (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wind32com

C:\>pip install shutil
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shutil 
(from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for shutil

C:\>pip install dateutil
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
dateutil (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dateutil 

C:\>pip install glob
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement glob 
(from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for glob

C:\>pip install fnmatch
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
fnmatch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fnmatch

C:\>pip install zipfile
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
zipfile (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for zipfile

C:\>python --version
Python 3.11.1

C:\>pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip 
(python 3.11)
```

Comment: All of those packages are either from the standard library or do not exist on PyPI. Where are you getting those names from?

Comment: It looks like you may be trying `pip install` the names of _import packages_, instead of the name of the distribution packages that provide them. E.g., there's the distribution `python-dateutil` that provides `dateutil`.

Comment: The name of the _package to install_ is not necessarily the same as the name of the _imported module_.  For example, the pip package name for dateutil is actually `python-dateutil`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question, you both are correct, but how do I know the distribution package name please?

Comment: @Franko If you go back to your Python 3.9 and run `python39  -m pip freeze --user` you should get a list of all your user installed distribution packages.  You could use `pip freeze --user > requirements.txt` to write to a file, and then `python311 -m pip install -u -r requirements.txt` to reinstall everything